# Find eigenvalue of a matrix that have all diagonal elements are zeros

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues of the matrix below:
>
> $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

As usual, I try to solve the equation below:
$\begin{vmatrix} - \lambda &0&2\\0&0&0\\2&0&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} = 0 $

But in this case the equation above give $ 0 = 0 $, and I got stuck.

What should I do?

Comment: The middle entry should also be $-\lambda$.

Comment: Assuming it wasn't just a mistyping, it would be interesting to know the reason why you skipped the central value, or why you though it ought to stay zero ? So we may help correcting the deeper misunderstanding rather than just say *"hey, you forget $-\lambda$ in the middle."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix:
$$\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda &0&2 \\0 &-\lambda & 0 \\ 2& 0 &-\lambda  \end{vmatrix}=-\lambda^3+4\lambda=\lambda(4-\lambda^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{vmatrix} - \lambda &0&2\\0&-\lambda&0\\2&0&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} = 0 $ is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant you have to compute is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -\lambda & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}=
-\lambda\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 2 \\
2 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=-\lambda(\lambda^2-4)
$$

Alternatively, you know that $0$ is an eigenvalue because the matrix is not invertible; also $2$ is an eigenvalue, because
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}=
2\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The sum of the eigenvalues is the trace, which is $0$, so the third eigenvalue is $-2$.